# Question on DDMS method profiler

Tags: android, profiler, ddms

I'd like to use the method profiler to see how many times particular methods are executed. However, everything I see in there is rather cryptic.

For example, all I'd like to see is how many times method doWork() is called. I simply can't find it. How do I do that?

Also, it seems like the android SDK has no documentation on how to use this feature. Does anyone have a guide somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know it's old question, but googled it when was lookin exacly for this same.

Here is some doc: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html
and here a very interesting video: http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/DebuggingArtsNinjaMasters.html

Cheers