# ViewPager setCurrentItem freezes UI thread

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am using a ViewPager from Android support v13 and I'd like to scroll to a specific item using `setCurrentItem(int)`, but when I try to scroll more than 2 pages the application freezes, and after a few seconds the system shows an ANR window.

I tried to increase the offscreen screen limit using `setOffscreenPageLimit(2)`, that way it did not freeze when i tried to scroll 2 pages, but did the same for 3 pages.

My problem is that my fragments are pretty memory consuming so I would not like to have too much in memory. I used the same code with support library v4, but I had to update it to v13 to use `NotificationCompat.Builder.addAction(int, CharSequence, PendingIntent)`.

Does any of you know what could be the problem, and what could be the solution?

Comment: You're probably doing too much work in the adapter. Post relevant code.

Comment: You could use the DDMS Method profiler to find out what is going on at the time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636746/question-on-ddms-method-profiler

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Is your adapter handling very large amounts of items? (very large > ~2<sup>20</sup> items)

[`ViewPager.populate(int)`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java#L1029) will loop from the current item position to [`N`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java#L1122), which is the number of items in the adapter - so if you've set it to something large (such as `Integer.MAX_VALUE`) this will takes some time, but will eventually finish.

If this is your case, search for "endless pager" related questions, such as [Endless ViewPager android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682726/endless-viewpager-android), or limit the number of items to something that's reasonable for the main thread.

Comment: It is a calendar, so it contains a large number of fragments. I will look at your solutions, thanks.

Comment: my only has 15 items, and app isn't responding when I have for example current position 3 and I set new with `setCurrentPosition` to 10 (from 3 to 10) then app becomes unresponsive, it works good only if I change from 0 to 1, 3 to 4 and so on, p.s. I use https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider which includes `InfinitePagerAdapter` class

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I used `PagerAdapter` for infinite scrolling.

```
public static final int INITIAL_OFFSET = 1000;
@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE / 2;
}
```

And started the `ViewPager` in this way:

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(INITIAL_OFFSET);
```

So to get rid of the freezing I wrote small function:

```
private void movePagerToPosition(int position) {
        int current = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
        int sign = current > position ? -1: 1;
        while (viewPager.getCurrentItem() != position){
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + sign, true);
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

i have this issue.
add below method to custom viewPager and use this.

```
private void setupCurrentItem(int cur)
    {
        try
        {
            Class<?> viewpager = ViewPager.class;
            Field mCurItemField = viewpager.getDeclaredField("mCurItem");
            mCurItemField.setAccessible(true);
            mCurItemField.set(this, cur);
        }
        catch (Exception ignored) {}
    }


setupCurrentItem(100);
setCurrentItem(100, false);
```